# C++ style menu bar in VB.NET?

Tags: c++, vb.net, menubar

Ive been looking a long time for this, but can't seem to find it. When I add a menu strip in vb .net, it looks like this:

[http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/4341/menu1sbo.jpg http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/4341/menu1sbo.jpg](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/4341/menu1sbo.jpg)

and I want it to look like the WinRar, Calculator, Notepad etc menus like this:

[http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/307/menu1a.jpg http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/307/menu1a.jpg](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/307/menu1a.jpg)

From what I gathered, in vb 6 you could create a mainmenu and do it this way, but in vb .net it seems like all there is is ugly menustrip.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to get dirty and create a CustomRenderer([ToolStripProfessionalRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.aspx)) to apply to the [ToolStripManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmanager.aspx)

Without rehashing to much, [this doc looks like a nice overview](http://windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/Tool%20Strips/ToolStrip%20GTM.doc) or you can always opt for the [Microsoft tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy4ys6z6.aspx)

menustrip is derived from toolstrip

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable XP theme support in your project settings. To do this, go to My Project in your Solution Explorer, and make sure "Enable XP Visual Styles" is checked under the Windows application framework properties group down near the bottom of the Application tab.

If this doesn't work, you might need to create an application manifest as described in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289524%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old but for anyone else interested, you can find this type of menu in the .NET framework components. Just right click the Toolbox -> Choose items -> .NET Framework Components and filter for  MainMenu. Works exactly like any other menu strip from what I've seen so far.